# NoReverseMatch in django (relative urls with templates)

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio

I tried many of the solutions published but neither of any solution works so that's why I am looking for the solution which helps me

I am trying this code:-please tell any error if I did

#in my basics_app.urls

```
from basics_app import views
from django.urls import path 

#template tagging
app_name='basics_app'

urlpatterns=[
    path('relative/',views.relative,name="relative"),
    path('other/',views.other,name="index again"),
]
```

#in my relative.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>relatives url page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>welcome to relatives url templates</h1>
        <a href="{% url 'basics_app:views.other' %}">other page</a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your template isnt right, try it like this:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('other/',views.other,name="other"),
]

    

<a href="{% url 'other' %}">other page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the link creation you try to create the link with the view function name. Instead you should use te the name-argument given in the path()-function (in urls.py)

In urls.py:

```py
app_name = 'yourapp'

urlpatterns=[
...,
path('relative/',views.relative,name="relative"),
...
```

In template:

```
<a href="{% url 'your_app:relative' %}">other page</a>
```

Comment: I use this and no error showing but this no use of it because I want to show the information provided in 'other' page that's why I use other

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
from . import views #HERE
from django.urls import path 

#template tagging
app_name='basics_app'

urlpatterns=[
    path('relative/',views.relative,name="relative"),
    path('other/',views.other,name="index again"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'basics_app:index again' %}">other page</a>
```

In your url tag in the template you should use the `app_name` and the `name` of the path:

```
'app_name:name'
```